# Android-PHP-JSON: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: php, android, json

I am trying to accesss a JSON Object that contains php results in android but I keep getting a a parser error, If i run the same php code on my web browser I don't get any errors.

Here's the Android code:

```
package com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

public class ModulesFragment extends Fragment {

    // To keep track of the counter, we need to add a global variable to the project,
    // along with a key for saving and restoring.
    static final String KEY_STUDENT_NUMBER = "studentNumber";
    String studentNumber = "";

    private static final int CODE_GET_REQUEST = 1024;
    private static final int CODE_POST_REQUEST = 1025;

    ProgressBar progressBar;
    ListView moduleListView;

    List < String > modulesEnrolled;

    View view;
    Button firstButton;


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_module, container, false);

        String extraStr;

        try {
            extraStr = getArguments().getString("studentNumber");
            Log.e("try studentNumber", "tried student number");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            studentNumber = "PT2014-1282";
            Log.e("catch studentNumber", "catched student number");
        }


        moduleListView = (ListView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.moduleListView);

        modulesEnrolled = new ArrayList<>();

        requestSubjectsEnrolled ();


        return view;

    } // end of onCreateView method


    // To receive notifications of application state change, 2 methods are needed
    // the onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() methods

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) {

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString(KEY_STUDENT_NUMBER, studentNumber);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onActivityCreated (savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            studentNumber = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_STUDENT_NUMBER);
        }

    }

    // save the data before the activity closes
    @Override
    public void onPause () {

        super.onPause();

        SharedPreferences settings = this.getActivity().getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString(KEY_STUDENT_NUMBER, studentNumber);
        editor.commit();
    }


    private void requestSubjectsEnrolled () {

        PerformNetworkRequest request = new PerformNetworkRequest(API.URL_REQUEST_SUBJECTS_ENROLLED+studentNumber, CODE_GET_REQUEST);
        request.execute();

    }

//    private void refreshSubjectsEnrolled ( JSONArray modules ) throws JSONException {
//        modulesEnrolled.clear();
//
//        for ( int i = 0; i < modules.length(); i++ ) {
//            JSONObject obj = modules.getJSONObject(i);
//
//            modulesEnrolled.add(
//                    obj.getInt("courseId"),
//                    obj.getString("moduleIds")
//            );
//        }
//
//        ModuleAdapter adapter = new ModuleAdapter( this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), modulesEnrolled );
//        moduleListView.setAdapter(adapter);
//    }

    public class PerformNetworkRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        String url;
        HashMap < String, String > params; // Store the names of the subjects enrolled
        int requestCode;

        PerformNetworkRequest ( String URL, int code ) {

            url = URL;
            requestCode = code;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

            Log.d("fetchModules", "Register Response: " + s.toString());

            super.onPostExecute(s);

            try {

                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(s);

                if (!object.getBoolean("error")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), object.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //refreshSubjectsEnrolled(object.getJSONArray("subjectsEnrolled"));
                    Log.d("fetchModules", "Register Response: " + s.toString());
                } else {



                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());

            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();

            if (requestCode == CODE_POST_REQUEST)
                return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(url, params);


            if (requestCode == CODE_GET_REQUEST)
                return requestHandler.sendGetRequest(url);

            return null;

        } // end of  doInBackground method

    } // end of PerformNetworkRequest class



    class ModuleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        Context context;
        List  moduleList;
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public ModuleAdapter (Context applicationContext, List moduleList) {

            this.context = context;
            this.moduleList = moduleList;
            inflater = ( LayoutInflater.from( applicationContext ) );

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return moduleList.size();

        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.module_listview, null );
            TextView moduleHeading = ( TextView ) convertView.findViewById( R.id.moduleHeading );
            ImageView icon = ( ImageView ) convertView.findViewById( R.id.icon );

            moduleHeading.setText((Integer) moduleList.get( position ));

            //icon.setImageResource( flags[ position ] );

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the PHP Api.php code:

```
<?php

require_once '../includes/init.php';
include 'subjectsEnrolled.php';

global $db;


//an array to display the response
$response = array();

//if it is an api call
//that means a get parameter named api call is set in the URL
//and with this parameter we are concluding that it is an api call
if( isset( $_GET[ 'apicall' ] )) {

    switch( $_GET[ 'apicall' ] ){

        case 'request_subjects_enrolled':

            if( isset( $_GET['studentNumber'] ) ) {

                    $response['error'] = false;
                    $response['message'] = 'modules retrieved successfully';
                    $response['subjectsEnrolled'] = getSubjectsEnrolled ( $_GET['studentNumber'] );


            } else {

                    $response['error'] = true;
                    $response['message'] = 'Some error occurred please try again';

            } // end of if( isset( $_GET['studentNumber'] ) )

            if ( !isset( $_GET['studentNumber'] ) ) {

                    $response['error'] = true;
                    $response['message'] = 'Nothing to collect, provide a student number please';

            } // end of if ( !isset( $_GET['studentNumber'] ) )

            break;


        } // end of switch

    } else {

        //if it is not api call
        //pushing appropriate values to response array
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = 'Invalid API Call';

    } // end of if( isset( $_GET[ 'apicall' ] )) {

        //displaying the response in json structure
        echo json_encode($response);
    ?>
```

Here's the modulesEnrolled.php:

```
    <?php

require_once '../includes/init.php';

function getSubjectsEnrolled( $studentNumber ) {

    global $db;

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare( $db, "SELECT courseId, moduleIds FROM moduleTaking WHERE studentNumber = ?" );
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $studentNumber);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($courseId, $moduleIds);

    $studentModules = array();
    $moduleTaking = array();

    while($stmt->fetch()){

        $moduleTaking['studentNumber'] = $studentNumber;
        $moduleTaking['courseId'] = $courseId;
        $studentModules['moduleIds'] = $moduleIds;

    }

    $moduleNames = array ();
    $counter = 0;

    $modules = explode (",", $moduleIds);

    foreach ($modules as $module) {

        $stmt = mysqli_prepare( $db, "SELECT moduleName FROM module WHERE moduleId = ?" );
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $module);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($moduleName);

        while($stmt->fetch()){

            array_push($moduleNames, $moduleName);

        }

    }

  // concatenate moduleTaking -> 'modulesNames'
    foreach ($moduleNames as $modules) {

        //echo ($modules)
        if ( $moduleTaking['moduleNames'] != "" ) {
            $moduleTaking['moduleNames'] = $moduleTaking['moduleNames'] .", " . $modules;
        }
        else {
            $moduleTaking['moduleNames'] = $modules;
        }

    }

    return $moduleTaking;
}
?>
```

This is the output of the JSON Object:

```
{"error":false,"message":"modules retrieved successfully","subjectsEnrolled":{"studentNumber":"PT2014-1282","courseId":1,"moduleNames":"Internet Programming and E-commerce, Operating Systems, Java and Distributed Systems"}}
```

And This is the error message:

```
10-29 17:17:16.239 6440-6440/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms D/fetchModules: onPostExecute Register Response:   []
    10-29 17:17:16.239 6440-6440/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
    10-29 17:17:16.244 6440-6440/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
    10-29 17:17:16.244 6440-6440/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:159)
    10-29 17:17:16.244 6440-6440/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
    10-29 17:17:16.244 6440-6440/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms W/System.err:     at com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms.ModulesFragment$PerformNetworkRequest.onPostExecute(ModulesFragment.java:165)
    10-29 17:17:16.244 6440-6440/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms W/System.err:     at com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms.ModulesFragment$PerformNetworkRequest.onPostExecute(ModulesFragment.java:138)
    10-29 17:17:16.244 6440-6440/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
    10-29 17:17:16.244 6440-6440/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
    10-29 17:17:16.244 6440-6440/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
    10-29 17:17:16.244 6440-6440/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    10-29 17:17:16.244 6440-6440/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    10-29 17:17:16.244 6440-6440/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
    10-29 17:17:16.244 6440-6440/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    10-29 17:17:16.244 6440-6440/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    10-29 17:17:16.244 6440-6440/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
    10-29 17:17:16.244 6440-6440/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
    10-29 17:17:16.244 6440-6440/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    10-29 17:17:16.244 6440-6440/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms E/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Comment: when you caused this problem ,you can use `JSONArray  jsonArray = new JSONArray(s);`  and try it .If you solved ,you can check you `result` .Alse you can check other code .

Comment: the array that is returned is empty so i end up getting Index 0 out of range

Comment: And show `Log.d("fetchModules", "Register Response: " + s.toString());` log info.

Comment: Added `Log.d("fetchModules", "onPostExecute Register Response: " + s.toString());`

Comment: So you get `[ ]` in your response .It was `JSONArray` .It just didn't have data in `JSONArray` .So check why you did not get and data in `JSONArray` .

Comment: How do I check?

Comment: You can add some data in server .Then you request it .And try again.

Comment: fixed it. had an URL problem.

Comment: Good luck to you.